# How can I initialise a Dictionary with delegate elements?

Tags: c#, dictionary, delegates

I want to create a static `Dictionary` which maps values to delegates. When using `Add` this works fine:

```
class MyClass {
    private delegate void _processStatement(Statement statement);

    private static Dictionary<Statement.Types, _processStatement> _statementProcessors = 
           new Dictionary<Statement.Types, _processStatement>();

    public MyClass() {
           _statementProcessors.Add(Statement.Types.Increment, Increment);
    }

    private void Increment(Statement s) {}
}
```

But, I would like to initialise them on instantiation, like this:

```
class MyClass {
    private delegate void _processStatement(Statement statement);

    private static Dictionary<Statement.Types, _processStatement> _statementProcessors = 
           new Dictionary<Statement.Types, _processStatement>() {
               { Statement.Types.Increment, Increment }
          }
    }
    private void Increment(Statement s) {}

}
```

Which gives me the error

> The best overloaded Add method 'Dictionary<Statement.Types, Machine._processStatement>.Add(Statement.Types, Machine._processStatement)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments

which I do not completely understand.

Is it even possible, what I am trying to achieve? Or do I have to initialise it in the constructor?

**Update** when adding it in the constructor I get this runtime error:

> An item with the same key has already been added. Key: Increment

Comment: How is Statement.Types.Increment a delegate of the prtivate delegate _processStatement?

Comment: `Statement.Types.Increment` is the key, the delegate `Increment()` is the value, in the dictionary.

Comment: Does dictionary initializer notation  `new Dictionary<, >() { [Statement.Types.Increment] = Increment }` work? If not you may need to use a cast, ie `(_processStatement)Increment` or maybe lambda notation `(Statement x) => Increment(x)` and see if the IDE recommends a code fix to make it more succinct

Comment: No I mean, have you tried the specific syntax I suggested. There's two types of collection Initializers you can use for dictionaries. One like you use, the other like I suggest (look closer, square brackets)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Yes, I got that, that's why I removed my comment. When I try that, I get the error `A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Machine.Increment(Statement)'`

Comment: Makes sense. That's your answer then and explains why the constructor version works. Try the lambda version, same error?

Comment: The lambda gives the same error. Which indeed makes sense.

Comment: Your dictionary is static yet you call add in the instance constructor. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, shouldn't you use a static constructor instead?

Comment: @KevinGosse I want a fixed list of processors, basically to avoid a large `switch` statement, for each `Statement`. But I am seeing the problem now; not the first time this `static` stuff is confusing me... :)

Comment: Wow I completely missed the static modifier. Now it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this code:

```
class MyClass {
    private delegate void _processStatement(Statement statement);

    private static Dictionary<Statement.Types, _processStatement> _statementProcessors = 
           new Dictionary<Statement.Types, _processStatement>() {
               { Statement.Types.Increment, Increment }
          }
    }
    private void Increment(Statement s) {}
}
```

You want to make the Dictionary static, but `Increment` is an instance method of `MyClass`. Think about that -- how would that work? In order for `Increment` to be called, `MyClass` needs to be instantiated, but you want to access it before that ever happens.

Your first example is correct...

Or, you could make `Increment` static:

```
class MyClass {
    private delegate void _processStatement(Statement statement);

    private static Dictionary<Statement.Types, _processStatement> _statementProcessors = 
           new Dictionary<Statement.Types, _processStatement>() {
               { Statement.Types.Increment, Increment }
          }
    }
    private static void Increment(Statement s) {}

}
```

Or, you could instantiate `MyClass` and reference the method:

```
class MyClass
{
    private delegate void _processStatement(Statement statement);

    private static Dictionary<Statement.Types, _processStatement> _statementProcessors;

    static MyClass()
    {
        var myClass = new MyClass();
        _statementProcessors = new Dictionary<Statement.Types, _processStatement>
        {
            { Statement.Types.Increment, myClass.Increment }
        };
    }

    private void Increment(Statement s) { }
}
```

Or, you could make a static instance of `MyClass`:

```
class MyClass
{
    private delegate void _processStatement(Statement statement);

    private static MyClass Instance { get; } = new MyClass();
    private static Dictionary<Statement.Types, _processStatement> _statementProcessors = new Dictionary<Statement.Types, _processStatement>
    {
        { Statement.Types.Increment, Instance.Increment }
    };

    private void Increment(Statement s) { }
}
```